# Springboot: trying to map a logout url - There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to map a logout url in spring boot application. Every other mapping I have specified is working perfectly but this logout url mapping is refusing to map to the controller

this is the form with the submit command

```
<form method="post" action="/livechat/logout">
        <input type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
</form>
```

this is the controller when you hit the submit button

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response) {
        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            if ("name".equals(cookie.getName()) || "email".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                // clear cookie
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

in my application.properties file I have this configuration for the server url definition

```
server.context-path= /livechat
#server port
server.port = 8081
```

When I click on logout i get this error

```
Fri Aug 05 11:56:22 WAT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

when I look at the url borwser it seems correct but I get error responce

```
http://localhost:8081/livechat/logout
```

Please what be wrong. Kiindly assist!

Comment: Are you using Spring Security or not? The HTML code of the form that you provided is a code from the template or it's HTML code that you have in you browser?